# Retrieve a childNode of a parent Node with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodes

I have a html table with this form :

```
<html>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th idth='keyth'></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class='edit' idtd='keytd'></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

Now I want in jquery to retrieve the content of the attribute 'keyth' departing from the edit class.
 Exemple:

```
$(".edit") {

    "th_id": this.parentNode.....childNode.getAttribute("idth"),
    //Here I dont know how to achieve the attribute content

});
```

Thank you for your suggestions!!!

I finally found a solution with only Javascript:

```
"th_id":this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].getAttribute("idth")
```

Comment: Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these work

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/yYM9V/)

```
$(function() {
  $(".edit").on("click",function() {  
    var $thWithKeyTd = $("th[idth='keyth']");

    var $parentChild = $(this).closest("table").find("th[idth='keyth']");  

  });            
});
```

Plain JS

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/LapUZ/)

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.querySelector(".edit").onclick=function() {  
    var thWithKeyTd = document.querySelector("th[idth='keyth']");
    console.log(thWithKeyTd.innerHTML);  
  };            
};
```

Comment: doesn'twork I think I must do 3 times parent() and 3 times children() but it doesn't work

Comment: How closest works with getAttribute?closest().getAttribute('')?

Comment: getAttribute is not jQuery

Comment: I think I need a solution with only Javascript I 'm mixing both Jquery and Javascript

Comment: Useful information before I wasted my time with jQuery. You can use querySelectorAll then

Comment: I also found a solution with pure Javascript,funny but true:"th_id":this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].getAttribute("idth")

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plain vanilla JS flavour and it's faster than jQuery solution

```
    "th_id" : this.offsetParent.querySelector('[keyth]')
```